# UITableView for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode4, tableview

I am very new to Objective-C. I just searched and tried to learn about `UITableView`.

I have created this `UITableView`. instead of `"a"` in all the rows i want it to be in a sequence like `"a b c d..."` and if i increase the no of rows it should scroll. its not scrolling so here is my code.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame  style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 20;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cellIDent"];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"a";
    return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: You need to go through some iOS tutorials. Check http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials. Also `[super viewDidLoad];` should be the first call in the method.

Comment: check out Apple's Reference @ http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I appreciate your interest to learn  cell for row at index will return cells one by one in order so here even the second cell returns a. try changing that logic and for scrolling see the below answers they are beautifully framed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: add these lines

```
char ch = 'a' + indexPath.row;
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c" , ch];
```

Comment: also in your viewDidLoad
    [tableView setScrollEnabled:YES];

Comment: thank you. its working for the index thing but the screen is still not scrolling.

Comment: add these two lines at the end of your viewDidLoad, and i am sure you will get it working
    [tableView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

Comment: and please move [super viewDidLoad]; to the top of your viewDidLoad, and let me know if it works.

Comment: i did that also but still i am not able to scroll.

Comment: @ShanuSingh kindly if can give me your code, so that i can check whats actualy the problem is. My skype id: bilal.jtisb

Comment: ya sure. i will send you my codes as soon as possible. thank you

Answer (score 2):

set table view Delegates in IB or if u created Programmatically then in viewDidLoad Take one array fill it Dynamically or Statically.Give array count in NumberOfRowsInsection method and reload table view at appropriate place

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial, I'm sure it will help you

[UItableView Guide](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/)

and for scrolling, You don't need to do anything yourselves, as the number of cells increases beyond the provided size, it automatically becomes scrollable and make sure that scrolling is enabled in your `UITableView` attribute inspector, check the image

[image]

Happy Coding

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.....define alphabetarr in globally then use it in code...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    alphabetarr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f",@"g",@"h",@"i",@"j",@"k",@"l",@"m",@"n",@"o",@"p",@"q",@"r",@"s",@"t",@"u",@"v",@"w",@"x",@"y",@"z", nil];

    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    UITableView *tableview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    tableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
    tableview.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    tableview.delegate = self;
    tableview.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableview];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [alphabetarr count];
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 30.0 ;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell!=nil) {
        cell = nil;
    }
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

        cell.textLabel.text = [alphabetarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```